# Best solution with twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a design that I want to translate to html/css with twitter bootstrap.
I know how to do everything except the header. What would be the best solution to make this in twitter bootstrap? I can slice all the images, ... .

This is an image of the header:
[image]

Does somebody know the best solution to make this in twitter bootstrap? (I am using the standard grid system)

Comment: At stackoverflow, we like to see the things that you have tried before answering your question, please attempt to get this working, if you run into any problems, then ask the question, here is a tip though, you make the nav, then you create the gray part under it, then you get the logo image set it to `position:absolute; top:0px; left:100px;` .. example

Comment: Should your header behave like i.e. the navbar of Bootstrap? If not, I would suggest to just feel free and create your own HTML + CSS for that part of your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span7"></div>
        <div class="span1">Home</div>
        <div class="span1">Over gdm</div>
        <div class="span1">Contact</div>
        <div class="span1"></div>
        <div class="span1">Aanmelden</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            <img src="?" alt="gdm clipboard" />
        </div>
        <div class="span4"></div>
        <div class="span2">
            Uploaden
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```